# Building maven project in Bamboo gives me an empty jar

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, pom.xml, bamboo

I'm working with Eclipse, Maven 2.0 and Bamboo. I checked out a project from GitHub and debugged it in Eclipse. I had it ready and when I exported the JAR from Eclipse I got a 76KB JAR (which is correct), but when I make Bamboo use a plan to build the same JAR using a maven pom.xml file, Bamboo gives me a 1KB JAR saying there's nothing to compile.

What am I missing? Here's my pom.xml file:

```xml
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>Lib</groupId>
      <artifactId>Lib</artifactId>
      <name>Lib</name>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <description>Lib</description>
      <dependencies>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.16</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
                <version>0.9</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.0-beta2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-email</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
           </dependency>
      </dependencies>
 </project>
```

Comment: Not enough info to go on; is it a normal Maven directory layout?